# Xcode 8.0 - App Installation Failed - The executable contains an invalid signature

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Made an app called MyFirstApp in Xcode 8.0 and I was ready to test it on my iPhone 6s. Plugged it in with the lightning cable it came with and pressed Window > Devices > iPhone 6s. Went down to the Installed Apps section pressed the + and selected the built application. Received the error "App Installation Failed - The executable contains an invalid signature."

Under the general tab for the app project I have "Automatically manage signing" checked with my name selected as the Team.

Provisioning Profile: Xcode Managed Profile

Signing Certificate: iPhone Developer (my name) (############)

Tried Product > Clean and Product > Build.

It feels like I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what my options are for fixing this. I'm building this in Swift 3 if that matters.

Answer (score 6):

ok I somehow stumbled across a fix.

Product > Destination > my iphone.

Then I pressed the run button. It asked if I wanted to add my phone as a valid developers device. After pressing yes, it then asked me 700 times to validate the app was ok to place on the phone.

Very strange I couldn't just press to send the app to the phone, but this works. If anyone has anything to add please do. This was a very confusing process for me.

Comment: You weren't joking about the 700 times... -_-

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that an App Store distribution provisioning profile was mistakenly used to sign the Ad Hoc build. Please note that builds signed with an App Store distribution provisioning profile cannot be installed onto development or testing iOS Devices; they can only be submitted to iTunes Connect for App Review. To resolve this issue, sign the app with an Ad Hoc distribution provisioning profile instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2319/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013778-CH1-ERRORMESSAGES

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned, rebuilt, uninstalled and reinstalled the app again. It fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I installed AppSync Unified from Cydia and it worked. However, this method requires a jailbreak.